# Instalar aplicativo IOS sem precisar subir na loja

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, angular, ionic2, appstore

É possível instalar um aplicativo IOS sem precisar subir na loja?
Assim como eu posso apenas baixar o .apk e instalar no android?

Um exemplo do que estou falando: http://www.gba4iosapp.com/download/

Se você acessar o link e clicar em download ele vai perguntar se você quer instalar o aplicativo, sem precisar acessar a loja do App Store.

Comment: Creio que sim. Mas para isso você tem que ter uma conta de desenvolvedor na Apple (Apple Developer). Daí no xml do seu projeto você informa o seu ID, que ao gerar o .app você conseguirá instalar em seu aparelho.

Comment: Eu tenho conta de desenvolvedor. Ele só gera uma pasta chamada Meu App.app. Até tentei subir essa pasta no meu servidor e acessar através do meu celular, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver, basta gerar o arquivo .ipa após gerar o archive e mandar exportar no Xcode 8.

Com isso também será gerado um arquivo chamado "manifest.plist", basta subir ambos os arquivos em um servidor por exemplo, e colocar uma tag em um html para o usuário clicar e fazer o donwload:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=<URL ABSOLUTA>/manifest.plist">Instalar App</a>
```